# Want to find out more about my Cannondale R900

Tags: vintage, road, cannondale

I just bought what appears to be a Cannondale R900 polished aluminum road bike and am wondering about the year. Has the following ID on the bottom bracket: EI 08018 BE246 3BOW54
Also interested in knowing what the bike came with new. Price also if it's available.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. You probably won’t get much information with what you have offered up. Serial numbers rarely give identification information. A picture would help. In fact, several identifying pictures.

Comment: Welcome - Please add a clear photo of your bike to the question, using [edit]

Comment: Are you happy with the answer, Robin?

Answer (score 3):

I had a polished R900 I bought from my employer once. I think it was a 1994 model, with cantilevered dropouts.

Original equipment was a full Shimano 600 (6400) 8-speed group, including hubs.

You can look through the catalogues at vintagecannondale.com to see if you can find a match. There aren't loads of polished R900 bikes so you can work it out with some effort.

The serial number suggests a 54cm and can be decoded to a september 93 mfg date for the 94 model year. I expect this is your bike:

[image]

Comment: Some of it can actually be decoded, EI means September 1993, so happy anniversary! https://vintagecannondale.com/info/serial_numbers/

Comment: @DoNuT well done!

Comment: It's teamwork - and as much "ID my bike" as you can get. ;-)